# Crop Image so It Becomes Full Screen like Snapchat

Tags: swift, image, uiimageview, uiimage

If you upload a picture to Snapchat (that isn't already full screen), it will zoom in and crop the photo so that it becomes full screen. I am able to do this in my ImageView using autoresizing masks, but I need to be able to save the image in this cropped state and I can't figure out how to do it.

This is how I am able to display the image (selected from camera roll) in the image view how I want it

```
let imgView = UIImageView(image: image)

        imgView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleTopMargin]
        imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imgView.clipsToBounds = true
        imgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

        self.view.addSubview(imgView)
```

This turns a non-full screen photo and displays it full screen with the propping zoom/crop. How can I now save the photo as a full screen photo?

Answer (score 0):

you can capture an image from given views.

```
func image(with view: UIView) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.isOpaque, 0.0)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        view.layer.render(in: context)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        return image
    }
    return nil
}

let img = image(with: YourImageView)
```

Comment: Will this drastically reduce the quality of the image since it is going from ~3000x4000 to like ~414x730? Or am I not thinking about that properly

Comment: yes, the dimension of image will be fit with your view.

Comment: How come the quality of the image appears the same as the original even though the resolution is dropping from ~3000x4000 to ~400x700? Is the iPhone not ever showing the ~3000x4000 because the screen is only ~400x700?

Comment: Yes, [Here](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions) are all iPhone resolution. by the way, `pt` is the resolution unit in iOS, which meant 2 or 3 times pixel which base on different devices.